# Exploding in php

Tags: php, mysql, explode

In my table 'users' there are 'friends' ,

Like this :

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | friends |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | a    | 0,1,2   |
|  2 | b    | 0,1,3   |
|  3 | c    | 0,1     |
+----+------+---------+
```

How do I use the explode function to get the friends id one by one (not 0,1,2) that are separated by a comma (,) ;

How do I select the id? (Example) :

```
$sql = Select id from users where id = (exploded)

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0 ) {
  $TPL->addbutton('Unfriend');
}else{
  $TPL->addbutton('Add as Friend')
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by one by one?

Comment: Noooooooooo!!!! Normalize your database properly.... otherwise you're guaranteeing yourself and anybody else that ever needs to look at your system to a lifetime of pain and anguish.... not to mention the fact that a kitten died the moment you made the decision to store all of the friends data in a column in your user table

Comment: Also, be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are obsolete and insecure. The are deprecated and not recommended for use. You should change your code to use either mysqli or PDO instead as soon as you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution here is actually a slight change in your database structure. I recommend you create a **"many-to-many"** relational table containing all of the users friends referenced by user.

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | firend_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         2 |
|       1 |         3 |
|       1 |         4 |
|       2 |         1 |
|       2 |         5 |
+---------+-----------+
```

If you are storing lists of values within one field then that is the first sign that your database design is not quite optimal. If you need to search for a numerical value, it'll always be better to place an index on that field to increase efficiency and make the database work for you and not the other way around :)

Then to find out if a user is a friend of someone, you'll query this table -

```
SELECT * FROM users_friends WHERE 
  `user_id` = CURRENT_USER AND `friend_id` = OTHER_USER
```

To get all the friends of a certain user you would do this -

```
SELECT * FROM users_friends WHERE `user_id` = CURRENT_USER
```

Comment: +1 although I'd suggest also having a unique ID field for this table as well as the two linking ID fields.

Comment: @SDC - an `id` field would be a bit redundant here. You would never really use it for anything. All you would have to do is make sure the two fields are unique together so that you prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple example that will make you clear how to proceed:

```
// Obtain an array of single values from data like "1,2,3"...
$friends = explode(',', $row['friends']);
```

Then, back in your query:

```
// Obtain back data like "1,2,3" from an array of single values...
$frieldslist = implode(',', $friends);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ('" . $frieldslist . "')";
```

Comment: Can we implode(seperate) a things that have been exploded(remove comma)

Answer (score 0):

to get an array of if ids from your string [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) would be used like this

```
$my_array = explode("," , $friends);
```

but you'd probably be better using the mysql [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause

```
$sql = "Select id from users where id in (".$row['friends'].")";
```

Comment: the `IN` clause is fine, as long as the contents of the `friends` field is *guaranteed* to contain only comma separated numeric values. If there's even the slightest possibility of contamination, then a SQL string like this could be an opportunity for a SQL injection attack. Even if you think it is safe, you'd be creating a situation where if an attacker could get an unsafe value into it, it would open you up to further attack. Because of that, I'd say that it would be best not to use `IN` directly on the field. It's better to code defensively and avoid even potential attacks.

Comment: of course, [you are correct](http://bobby-tables.com/); i was really just directing the op to the in clause to get mysql to do some of the work. be vigilant kids!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea. Change your database's table. It is certain that after a while many problems will arise.

You could have something like this.

```
    id      hasfriend
    1          2
    1          3
    2          1 no need to be here (You have this already) 
    2          4 
       .....
```

You can do this by using indexes for uniqueness or programming. You may think of something better. Change your approach to the problem to something like this.